# Add context menu item for optical drive

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, optical-drive

What is the registry key(s) that controls the PC's optical drive right click context menu. Assume that I have a program called *Erase.exe* that would erase a RW/RE media (or any other exe for that matter), I need to add a key to that menu that would open the target executable program if possible also without resorting to external `dll`s or registry tweakers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to add the option would be to do so for *all* drives, as shown below, in the Registry Key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\windirstat\command`.

[image: Add shell context menu item]

Use the model for *WinDirStat*. Point to the executable in key `command`, and you can include an icon in the key above it, e.g. value name: `icon`, type: REG_SZ, data: `"full path to application", icon_number`.

Of course, there is the disadvantage that this would show for *all* drives, not just optical; but I do not know the Registry key for only optical drives... If anyone does, please edit this or post that as a comment!